# Aspect Ratio of images on the fly

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, aspect-ratio

I have a function that pulls images from an external location and the arrive with the proportions of `952 x 390` but they are displayed on my site `960 by 380` is there anyway using PHP that I could change the ratio so they do not look so stretched?

Comment: quick - you can just specify it in the image tag, img width=, height=, most browsers will display that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [codigniters Image Library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/image_lib.html)  and parse maintain_ratio as one of the attributes

```
 $this->load->library('image_lib');

 $params = array();
 $params['source_image'] = /path/to/image
 $params['new_image'] = /path/to/mynewimage
 $params['width'] = 960;
 $params['height'] = 380; //leave height or with only for aspect ratio to work
 $params['maintain_ratio'] = true;
 $this->image_lib->initialize($params);
 $this->image_lib->resize();
```

Comment: Thanks,  interms of the source_image & new_image does this mean I have to save them to server?

Comment: Yes they will have to be on the server. Won't you need to crop them, rather than resize them?